# Cloud not install the plug-in Properties Editor for Eclipse(Kepler)

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, properties

I've downloaded two versions of Propedit, jp.gr.java_conf.ussiy.app.propedit_5.3.3.zip and ...6.0.5, and tried many ways to install it, but all failed.

#### Way 1

Unzip them to the directory `eclipse/dropins`.

#### Way 2

After unzipping them, copy the stuffs in the path `features` and `plugins` to the appropriate path of eclipse.
By the way, the version 6, its features shipped as a JAR file, I've tried directly copy the JAR file and also unzip the JAR file.

However, they all did not work.

#### ENV

- JDK: 1.6.0_45(64-bit)
- Eclipse: Java EE IDE(Kepler Service Release 2)
- OS: Win7

What could I do?
Any suggestion?
Thanks.

*NOTE: I prefer installing it OFFLINE to online.*

---

**UPDATE**

I used the version 5.3 for MyEclipse, just drop into the directory `dropins`.
Does the Eclipse miss some features?

Comment: Were there no instructions given *with the download*?

Comment: @nitind NO. I found some info from other websites, almost the same solutions as I said above. They all did not work for me, for eclipse of this version